# Getting 'Cannot find an overload for "checkVat" and the argument count' error with VIES SOAP service using Powershell

Tags: powershell, soap, powershell-4.0

I'm trying to use PowerShell (using version 5.0) to check VAT numbers using the VIES Soap webservice.

I'm getting the following error:

```
'Cannot find an overload for "checkVat" and the argument count: "2".'
```

From what I see in the wsdl file, the `checkVat` function accepts two string values, the `countryCode` and `vatNumber`.

This is the code I'm using:

```
$proxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri "http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl"
Try{
    $response = $proxy.checkVat("ES","A28017895")
    $response
}Catch{
    $_.Exception.Message
}
```

What's causing the error?

Answer (score 0):

well, the checkVat function takes more parameter, you also need to use the `[ref]` keyword. Here an working example:

```
$proxy.checkVat([ref]"ES",[ref]"A28017895", [ref]$true, [ref]"", [ref]"")
```

Comment: According to the wsdl, that signature matches the response message type, not the input parameters. Something causes `New-WebProxyService` to misinterpret it

Comment: Thanks for your support jisaak.

It's not not throwing an error, but still not fully understanding a couple of things:

1. could you help explain where it says that there are a total of five parameters for the ´checkVat´function in the WSDL file?
2. In the response (´checkVatResponse´) I was expecting between four and six fields. The most relevant one being the boolean ´valid´. I only see a date in the response, which I presume is the ´requestDate´. How do I see if the sent VAT is valid?
3. What does ´[ref]´ stand for?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was recently reading [this article](https://scotthelme.co.uk/how-the-eu-made-our-website-slow/) and wanted to test the Vies database with PowerShell and came across this post.

Basically the word `[ref]` stands for a value that is passed by reference. Meaning if you define a local object, and pass it to a new method, it will point to the defined local object and any changes that are made will reflect back. By default the object is passed by value, and any changes made within the method will not change the local object.

See below script and output example:

```
Function Get-ViesVatNumber {
[CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                   Position=0)]
        $CountryCode,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                   Position=1)]
        $VatNumber
    )

    $Vies = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri "http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl" -Class "checkVat"

    $Valid = $false
    $Name = ""
    $Address = ""

    $DateChecked = $Vies.checkVat([ref]$CountryCode, [ref]$VatNumber, [ref]$Valid, [ref]$Name, [ref]$Address)

    $Properties = @{
        'CountryCode'   = $CountryCode
        'VatNumber'     = $VatNumber
        'Valid'         = $Valid
        'Name'          = $Name
        'Address'       = $Address
        'DateChecked'   = $DateChecked
    }

    $Company = New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property $Properties

    Write-Output $Company
}
```

Example with a valid VAT

```
Get-ViesVatNumber -CountryCode "BE" -VatNumber "0420429375"

DateChecked : 02/08/2018 00:00:00
Name        : Comm.VA ALPRO
VatNumber   : 0420429375
Address     : VLAMINGSTRAAT 28
              8560 WEVELGEM
Valid       : True
CountryCode : BE
```

Example with an invalid VAT

```
Get-ViesVatNumber -CountryCode "BE" -VatNumber "0420429335"

DateChecked : 02/08/2018 00:00:00
Name        : ---
VatNumber   : 0420429335
Address     : ---
Valid       : False
CountryCode : BE
```